# Spring Boot test @After not deleting rows before next test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test

I have the following @Before and @After in my Spring Boot integration tests:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac)
        .addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain).build();

    user = userRepository.save(
        new User("Joe", "Bloggs", "joe@example.com", "joe", passwordEncoder.encode("secret")));

    currency = currencyRepository.save(
        new Currency("GBP", "&pound;%01.2f"));

    fund = fundRepository.save(
        new Fund("Nationwide", (double) 100, currency));

}

@After
public void teardown() {
    userRepository.delete(user);
    currencyRepository.delete(currency);
    fundRepository.delete(fund);
}
```

However, it doesn't seem that currencies are being deleted after each test and my tests are failing in error:

```
...
[ERROR] testGetFunds_whenNoToken_thenUnauthorized(biz.martyn.budget.FundsControllerTest)  Time elapsed: 3.268 s  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find biz.martyn.budget.currency.Currency with id 437; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find biz.martyn.budget.currency.Currency with id 437
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find biz.martyn.budget.currency.Currency with id 437
...
```

After, if I query the test database, I see that rows haven't been deleted:

```
mysql> select * from currencies;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+------+---------------------+
| id | created_at          | deleted_at          | format        | name | updated_at          |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+------+---------------------+
...
| 437 | 2020-01-02 13:51:24 | 2020-01-02 13:51:23 | &pound;%01.2f | GBP  | 2020-01-02 13:51:24 |
...
+----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

There should only be one unique entry for name but I guess as delete is not happening it is pulling duplicates for "GBP". My repository for currencies:

Currency.java

```
@Entity(name = "currencies")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE currencies SET deleted_at = now() WHERE id = ?")
@Where(clause = "deleted_at is null")
public class Currency {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  protected Integer id;

  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String format;

  @Column(name = "created_at", updatable = false)
  @CreationTimestamp
  protected LocalDateTime createdAt;

  @Column(name = "updated_at")
  @UpdateTimestamp
  protected LocalDateTime updatedAt;

  @Column(name = "deleted_at")
  protected LocalDateTime deletedAt;

  protected Currency() {}

  public Currency(String name, String format) {
    this.name = name;
    this.format = format;
  }

  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getFormat() {
    return format;
  }

  public void setFormat(final String format) {
    this.format = format;
  }
}
```

User.java

```
@Entity(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8507204786382662588L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String surname;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Fund> funds;

    protected User() {}

    public User(String firstName, String surname, String email, String username, String password) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.email = email;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    // standard getters and setters

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public List<Fund> getFunds() {
        return funds;
    }

    public void addFund(Fund fund) {
        funds.add(fund);
        fund.setUser(this);
    }

    public void removeFund(Fund fund) {
        funds.remove(fund);
        fund.setUser(null);
    }

    // public Fund getFund(int id) {
    //  fundRepository.findByIdAndUserId(id)
    //         .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Fund ID not found: "+id));
    // }
}
```

Comment: Is it a SpringBootTest or a DataJpaTest?

Comment: And how is the Index UK_abaar0d2ymp2spkrkjnekr1h8 defined?

Comment: It's SpringBootTest. I've no idea where the UK_... string is defined, none of my columns or properties are named that.

Comment: Annotate your test class(es) that deals with database operations with `@Transactional` and you should be all set; otherwise try to use `@DataJpaTest` instead.

Comment: Is there any attriubte in the Currency entity or any other entity attribute declared as unique?

Comment: Not that I know. I've updated my post with Currency.java entity now.

Answer (score 0):

The `delete` method takes an object of `Currency`. Your `Currency` object has an ID which is auto-generated.

When you pass the same object that you passed to `save` to `delete` you did not set the ID that's the reason the delete operation never actually deletes the data you wanted to delete.

You can either use the object that is returned from `save` method or get a hold of the genearted-id and use `deleteById` method.

Here is an example for delete using the object.

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    user = repository.save(user);
}
```

```
@After
public void tearDown() {
    repository.delete(user);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the same object to get the generated-id and use `deleteById` method.

If you take a look at `SimpleJpaRepository` which provides an implementation for JPA, you will find that if your ID is null then they are treated as a new entity and are never deleted.

```
    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository#delete(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    @Transactional
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void delete(T entity) {

        Assert.notNull(entity, "Entity must not be null!");

        if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
            return;
        }

        // Other stuff
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I assumed it would just setId in the newly initiated instance within save(), updated my code and post now. Anyway, still seeing errors but different from before so I've updated that too. It's complaining that the currency ID doesn't exist but as before I can see it in the MySQL console after tests have run. Also, strangely users are deleted, at the end I have an empty table as desired for that. The only difference between User and Currency/Fund is that User implements Serialize. Tried that, but same.

Comment: @Martyn - It would be better if you can post the `User` entity as well. Do you Have `SQLDelete` for User entity? If you have similar update query then the table should not be deleting the rows from table.

Comment: Hi. I've added User now. Right enough, it's the only one that doesn't have SQLDelete. It should have though, I must have forgot to add it. However, I thought that delete() would handle that as it's also an annotation of Hibernate. Is there another method for "deleting" I ought to use when implementing soft deletes?

Comment: @Martyn, now your question is a lot different than what you asked initially. In the initial question, you had issue with records not getting deleted. The ask is now very different. I would recommend creating a new question so that if someone is having the same issue as you can refer this question for help. If the answers here solve the initial problem you mentioned, please remember to upvote or accept an answer.

Comment: Sure. I'm still having issues with it but it may be related to SQLDelete being attached to some entities, and not other entities. I probably need to spend a little more time on that area and report back if needed. Shall I delete this post? It's not really resolving the issue so perhaps not of use to anyone.